# Typescript check for array of objects

Tags: typescript

How to change value type so that I will get typescript error if I add more items to enum SomeEnum ( e.g. Four and Five )

I am aware of `in` operator, but couldn't apply it to a value. It works for keys.

```
enum SomeEnum {
  One,
  Two,
  Three,
  Four, //<- new item
  Five //<- new item
}

//How to change value type so that I will get typescript error if I add more items to enum SomeEnum ( e.g. Four and Five ) 
export const SomeConstant: {text: string, value: SomeEnum}[] = [
  {
    text: 'One',
    value: SomeEnum.One
  },
  {
    text: 'Two',
    value: SomeEnum.Two
  },
  {
    text: 'Three',
    value: SomeEnum.Three
  },
];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-zm5zq7?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6PpYm)

Comment: So you want your array to have all enum values? Or just the first three?

Comment: i want to add Four and Five to enum and get error in SomeConstant saying that i miss Four and Five

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a Map:

```
let mymap = new Map<SomeEnum, string>([
  [SomeEnum.One, "One"],
  [SomeEnum.Two, "Two"],
....
]);
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem at all.